# Visual Studio C# - Can I extract a piece of text to a string variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I have the same string of text typed at numerous locations in my program, is there any way I can extract this to a string variable and, at each location where this was originally typed, have the code instead point to this one variable?

For example, I have the following code:

```
if(File.Exists("C:\\whatever.txt"))
{
    File.Delete("C:\\whatever.txt");
}
```

Can I refactor that into this:

```
string s1 = "C:\\whatever.txt";

if(File.Exists(s1))
{
    File.Delete(s1);
}
```

I know this is what I should have done initially, but lets say I'm getting the logic of a program sorted first, then I come along after to tidy up my code, are there any shortcuts in Visual Studio to allow me to do this or would I need to do so manually?

Thanks

Comment: em, hi, find & replace is not enough?

Comment: I know I can use find and replace, was just wondering if there was a slicker alternative, @Tigran I guess I could open up the *.cs file in Notepad and do a find and replace on the text itself? However, people below have suggested Resharper which I shall look into =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you can just select the first string, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to introduce a variable. For identical strings, it will ask you if you want both to be replaced by the variable you introduce.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is another good keyboard shortcut which also shows you other refactoring options like introduce parameter, field, variable etc.

If you use Visual Studio you really should have Resharper imo!

Comment: It was difficult to choose a best answer, as they were all pretty similar but this one had the most detail! Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a feature like that in Visual Studio, but Resharper has it: it's called the Extract Variable refactoring. I'm really used to its keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

A nice thing about it is that it asks whether to replace all occurences of the string, or just the selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper is a really good tool for this kind of thing. It's a visual studio plugin available here
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Once installed you can use Ctrl+Shift+R to remove magic strings like this. You could also use the visual studio Find and Replace function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it manually. If you use the same path in many places in your application you can also store it in you configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably it might be best to do it manually, unless you have Resharper, also be weary of the differences in [String Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and how they can effect your code.